# AndEngine multiple activity error when switching

Tags: android-activity, nullpointerexception, andengine, splash-screen, onresume

Im using a splash screen for my andengine game the game crashes after the splash screen i have posted the error

```
05-18 19:49:19.939: E/AndroidRuntime(3425): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 19:49:19.939: E/AndroidRuntime(3425): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-18 19:49:19.939: E/AndroidRuntime(3425): at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onResumeGame(BaseGameActivity.java:221)
05-18 19:49:19.939: E/AndroidRuntime(3425): at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity$4.run(BaseGameActivity.java:372)
05-18 19:49:19.939: E/AndroidRuntime(3425): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-18 19:49:19.939: E/AndroidRuntime(3425): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-18 19:49:19.939: E/AndroidRuntime(3425): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-18 19:49:19.939: E/AndroidRuntime(3425): at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-18 19:49:19.939: E/AndroidRuntime(3425): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-18 19:49:19.939: E/AndroidRuntime(3425): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-18 19:49:19.939: E/AndroidRuntime(3425): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
05-18 19:49:19.939: E/AndroidRuntime(3425): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
05-18 19:49:19.939: E/AndroidRuntime(3425): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

for reference here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="busgame.tilt.basic"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<supports-screens
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:smallScreens="true"
            android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".Main" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
</activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

im pretty sure my andengine is up to date
 hope u guys can help 
thanks in advance

Comment: the most up to date "official" source is here https://github.com/nicolasgramlich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to all of your Andengine activities in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: but one problem.. the screen view in landscape as it should. but my textures are clipped to portrait size.. ant idea..

Comment: Doesn't sound like it's related to this. Check your engine options. Maye you switched it?

Comment: ya some bug in manifest now cleared..all fine works great... thanks a lot

Comment: @Alex: I am facing same problem, game is in portrait size. Can you share what you did to solve that problem?

Comment: Got it. Had to set android:screenOrientation="landscape" in manifest